# Laravel is not responding

Tags: php, laravel

So I've installed laravel just as it described in the official laravel docs on my local machine via both Laravel Installer and composer but then when I open   the site from chrome it gives me `The lara.loc page isn’t working` error. I've replaced code in the public/index.php file with code echoing random string and it has worked. So I think there's something wrong with the framework but I don't know exactly what.

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04,
Http server is Apache/2.4.20
PHP version is 5.6.21

Comment: Is there any `.env.example` file in your project's root then change it to `.env` then run `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: There were both `.env.example` and `.env` files so I deleted the  `.env.example` and ran `php artisan key:generate` which  was successfull, but it did not help

Comment: Try setting the permissions of the storage and bootstrap/cache folders.

Comment: I changed permissions but it not helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you Correctly configured your web serve, and your host file. Laravel throws a silent error when you don't have site key generated in your .env. You can check the error in your laravel logs.

Laravel has a command to autogenerate this key:

```
$ php artisan key:generate
```

Another approach if the storage folder is writable for the server. For testing proposes you can run the next from your project root:

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 storage
$ sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap
```

Comment: Better yet, run `php artisan optimize` and you'll see all the issues you need to resolve.

Comment: I've ran `php artisan key:generate` which was successfull, but it did not help

Comment: Take a look to the update if not work take a look to to the file storage/logs/laravel.log and see what happened that if the error is a 500 if not something is pissed of in your web server configuration.